# Connect a JDBC Java Client to SQL Developer on localhost

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I dont know how to connect my Java Client with JDBC to my SQL Developer Database on localhost with the 1521 port. My SQL Developer is running.

Im sure about username and password - but I think my connstring is set incorrectly. I treid to use it like the usage in the oracle docs. But I always get an error in my OracleDriver catch block. And Im also wondering how I can hand over the name of my Database to the driver, which is "GremienDatenbank".

**Here is my code:**

```
package com.company;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String connstring ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe";

    System.out.println("Username");
    String user = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Passwort");
    String pwd = br.readLine();

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connstring,user,pwd);


    } catch (IOException ioe){

        ioe.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {

        System.out.println("Fehler: " + cnfe.getMessage());

    } catch (SQLException se) {

            se.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the error that you've got.

Comment: SQL Developer is a java client development tool. There is not a DB included. Get Oracle XE here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html

Comment: The error is just "Fehler: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"

Comment: Fehler in german means Error^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");`

Comment: Do you have oracle jdbc jar at your classpath?

Comment: No - Do i have to import it?+

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: Do You know where I can get that file specifically for the SQL Developer?

Comment: Sql developer is a java client application. You want to connect to oracle database but not to sql developer APP. Google for jdbc jar for ORACLE.

Comment: Ok that should be the problem then - thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest 18.3 JDBC driver from [OTN](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html)